# Unable to find 'com/extjs/gxt/ui/GXT.gwt.xml' in GXT sample application

Tags: eclipse, gwt, extjs, gxt

I'm trying to run a sample application using GXT (ExtJS + GWT) as described in the tutorial at

http://www.sencha.com/learn/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse

When I try to run the application in eclipse, I get the error

```
Loading modules
   com.hello.gxt.HelloGXT
      Loading inherited module 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/extjs/gxt/ui/GXT.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 15: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

My build path looks like this

[image]

and the build path of the run configuration looks like this

[image]

Here's the source: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_09_27_HelloGXT.zip

How can I fix the problem?

'Update 29.09.2012': The former error is fixed, but now I get another one:

```
Loading modules
   com.hello.gxt.HelloGXT
      Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
         Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
            Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
               [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You might find this useful when following old tutorials: http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-gxt-2x-to-300-migration-guide/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your *.gwt.xml file from:

```
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
```

to

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
```

The tutorial you used is definitely for version 2.0.  From GXT 3.0, the namespace changed to com.sencha.gxt...

UPDATE - to answer the next issue:

I think you are missing gwt-dev.jar

See this for reference: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?73617-GWT-1.64-Class-not-found-exception-GXT-module-declaration-is.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the original error. But now I'm getting another one (class not found, see "Update 29.09.2012"). Any ideas?

Comment: Try bumping your GWT version to 2.4 or 2.5.0-rc1.